# Logic behind time limited comment editing

Tags: discussion, comments, rules

What is the logic behind disallowing edits to my comments after `x` minutes?  I can still copy the comment; paste it into a new comment; edit it; the delete the old one.   The result is the same.

This seems like a pointless bureaucratic obstacle; but I've come to suspect that nothing on this site is accidental or thoughtless.  What is the thinking behind this?

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33997/please-ditch-the-five-minute-window-on-comment-editing